# CSS Newbie - How to dynamically move buttons

Tags: jquery, css

I have a form that I'm modifying after it's been rendered via jquery - only because I have no control over the code that creates the form.

In any case, I'm adding a button beside the login button that's a part of the form.  In order to do this, I'm using the following jquery:

```
$('.mynewbutton').hide();
$(".submit").addClass("buttonalign");
$('<div class="shared">').insertBefore($('.submit'));
$('.submit').after($('<div class="circle circlealign">i</div>'));
```

The new button I'm adding is actually a circle that I've drawn using css. 
This works fine - the new button is aligned with the login. 
Here's the css:

```
.shared {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
}

.buttonalign {
    position: absolute;
    top:340px;
}

.circlealign {
    position: absolute;
    top:340px;
}
```

The problem I need to resolve is when the login form returns an error message, it displays the error at the top of the form and pushes everything down. 
So my login button and the new button end up covering over some other elements on the form because their position is fixed.

I changed the fixed numbers to percentages and em like so:

```
.shared {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}

.buttonalign {
    position: absolute;
    top:40em;
}

.circlealign {
    position: absolute;
    top:40em;
}
```

But that has change the position of the new button so that it no longer is aligned with the login button.  it's way lower on the page.
Can you point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

**EDIT 1**

Here's the rendered HTML.. and ofcourse the jquery stuff doesn't appear here which is a pain.. but you can see what the initial form looks like

```
<H1>Login</H1><DL>
<P class="err">Logon Failed</P>
<form action="/cgi-bin/logon/logon" method="POST">
<DT>User ID</DT>
<DD>
<input class=" text" type="text"  name="userid">
</DD>
<DT>Password</DT>
<DD>
<input class=" password" type="password"  name="password" >
</DD>
<DT></DT><DD><input class="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Logon">
</DD>
</FORM></DL>
```

Comment: hard to tell without the HTML... but what about `clear:both` in your css?

Comment: i've updated my post to include html... and i also tried the clear:both but that didn't change anything.  mind you, i'm not too sure which class you wanted me to add it to.

Comment: Thanks for the code, but any chance you have a jsfiddle or codepen we could check this out in?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/limark67/6UwWN/  In Firefox it looks correct.  But in IE, the button is misaligned.  And for some reason, when i run my jsfiddle in IE, the button doesn't appear at all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm having a hard time seeing why you're using absolute positioning at all, so if that's necessary for some reason, forgive me. My solution would be to wrap the existing button in a div and then add your custom button into that container. Then you can position your elements inside that container and they'll get pushed down with everything else when the error message comes back.

HTML:

```
<H1>Login</H1>
<DL>
<P class="err">Logon Failed</P>
<form action="/cgi-bin/logon/logon" method="POST">
<DT>User ID</DT>
<DD>
    <input class=" text" type="text"  name="userid"/>
</DD>
<DT>Password</DT>
<DD>
    <input class=" password" type="password"  name="password" />
</DD>
    <DT></DT>
    <DD><input class="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Logon"/>
</DD>
</form></DL>
```

CSS:

```
#actionButtons > * {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 2px;
}

#actionButtons:after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: block;
}
```

jQuery (wrapped in DOM ready function):

```
$(function(){
    $('.submit').wrap('<div id="actionButtons"/>');
    $('#actionButtons').append($('<div class="circle circlealign">i</div>'));
});
```

**UPDATE** - Circle CSS:

```
.circle {
    display: block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    background: #d1d1c9;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #000;
    opacity: 0.95;

    font: italic bold 2em/1em "Times New Roman";
    text-align: center;
    color: #000;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #666;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ebTS2/1/

Comment: i just tried your css.  its working better than the css i had come up with.  the only trouble is that the circle now is just not aligned to begin with!  I've updated the post to include the definition of my circle class

Comment: You had a lot of duplicate and unnecessary properties, so I cleaned it up for you. See the updated answer. If you want the circle to be a different size or aligned differently, you're going to have to play with the numbers. If I helped answer your question, please make this the selected answer.

Comment: theJoeBiz, the problem was the margin: 0px 0px 0px 400px; setting!  I changed to 300 and it works.

Comment: Yep, once you get a good handle on the box model, CSS is a breeze!

Answer (score 0):

If the error is returned within a DIV tag, perhaps you can use [jQueryUI's `dialog()` method](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) to display the error message, then hide the div?

```
    $( "#myError" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: true,
        height: 300,
        width: 350,
        modal: true,
                close: function() {
                    $('#ErrorDIV').hide();
                }
        });
```

Comment: gibberish, can i do this even if the <P> tag that has the error message in it has no name? <P class="err">Logon Failed</P>.  The other trouble is that this changes the behavior of the app so I'm not sure they'd like it.  I'd prefer another solution... if possible.  Thanks though